# How can I sort a specific range of elements in a list?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting, range

Suppose I have a list,

```
lst = [5, 3, 5, 1, 4, 7]
```

and I want to get it ordered from the second element 3 to the end.

I thought I could do it by:

```
lst[1:].sort()
```

But, this doesn't work.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
lst = lst[0:1] + sorted(lst[1:])
```

Answer (score 8):

```
lst = [5, 3, 5, 1, 4, 7]
lst[1:] = sorted(lst[1:])
print(lst) # prints [5, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
so = lambda x, index: x[:index]+sorted(x[index:])
```

so call it as so(lst, 1)

```
In [2]: x = [5, 3, 5, 1, 4, 7]
In [3]: so(lst, 1)
Out[4]: [5, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
lst = [5, 3, 5, 1, 4, 7]

searchValue = 3

def get_sorted(lVals, searchVal=None, startIndex=None):
    if startIndex and startIndex < len(lVals):
        return lVals[:startIndex] + sorted(lVals[startIndex:])         
    elif searchVal and searchVal in lVals:
        valueIndex = lst.index(searchValue)
        return lVals[:valueIndex] + sorted(lVals[valueIndex:])
    return sorted(lVals)
```

Comment: Is it so bad? Is it throwing exception? Is it not doing what expect?

Comment: It's trying too hard to guess everything that the OP could mean, instead of demanding that OP be more clear, as you should :)

Answer (score 0):

Its best to do it within the slice.

```
>>> lst = [5, 3, 5, 1, 4, 7]
>>> lst[1:]=sorted(lst[1:])
>>> lst
[5, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```